# Zeppelin Spark Interpreter: disable _spark_metadata when reading from HDFS data written by Spark Structured Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, metadata, apache-zeppelin, spark-structured-streaming

We have a stream implemented with Spark Structured Streaming writing to an HDFS folder and thus creating the _spark_metadata subfolder, in order to achieve the exactly-once guarantee when writing to a file system.

We additionally have a mode, in which we re-generate the results of the stream for historical data in a separate folder. After re-processing has finished, we copy the re-generate subfolders under the "normal-mode" folder. You can imagine that the _spark_metadata of the "normal-mode" folder is not up-to-date anymore and this causes incorrect readings of this data in Zeppelin.

Is there a way to disable the use of the folder _spark_metadata when reading with spark from a HDFS folder?